# Convergence of $\int_0 ^\infty \frac {dx}{\sqrt {1+x^3}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

Convergence of $\int_0 ^\infty \dfrac {dx}{\sqrt {1+x^3}}$

**Attempt:** $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac {x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt {1+x^3}} =1$

Hence, $\dfrac {1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ and $\dfrac {1}{\sqrt {1+x^3}}$ converge/diverge together.

$\int_0 ^\infty \dfrac {dx}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ does not converge since, it's not defined at $0$.

However, my textbook says this integral is convergent. Why is it so?

Thank you for reading through!

Comment: Thanks for including the work you've done so far.

Comment: Just because a function is not defined at $0$ doesn't mean that the function can't be integrated with $0$ a limit of integration. That's one of the main points of improper integrals, which is presumably what you're learning.

Comment: $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$ is no problem. For $\int_1^\infty$, use your argument.

Comment: @QuinnCulver I get it :) . Yeah, I just started with improper integrals

Comment: Let $t=\dfrac1{1+x^3}$ , and then see [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: @Wanderer You have been told to avoid double dollar signs in titles. Please remember to do so. Double dollar signs in title render like $$\text{ this}$$ instead of rendering like $\text{this}$ (inline). This makes titles messy in the main site. Regards,

Comment: @PedroTamaroff  I think the system doesn't allow the question to be posted itself if there's a double dollar signs in titles. Did you mean use of \dfrac in titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got some good answers but I want to highlight some of the reasoning errors you made.  It's important to derive your assertions carefully.

> Hence, $\dfrac {1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ and $\dfrac {1}{\sqrt {1+x^3}}$ converge/diverge together.

Remember that convergence is a property of the improper integral, not the function being integrated.  So a statement like “$\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$ converges” is ambiguous.  What you mean is

> > Hence, $\color{red}{\int_1^\infty}\frac {1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\color{red}{\,dx}$ and $\color{red}{\int_1^\infty}\frac {1}{\sqrt {1+x^3}}\color{red}{\,dx}$ converge/diverge together.

This is true.  Now for this:

> $\int_0 ^\infty \frac {dx}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ does not converge since, it's not defined at $0$.

A couple of problems here.  One is that you have two improper integrals in one.  Both $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}$ and $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}$ are improper.  But only the second one is relevant for this problem.  That's because $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$ is *not* improper, so you are only worried about whether $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$ converges.

As for $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}$, you are correct that it does not converge, but it does *not* follow from your assertion that the integrand is not defined at $0$.  After all, $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^{1/2}}$ does converge, but the integrand is not defined at $0$ either.  The divergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}$ follows from the $p$-test: if $p > 1$ then $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^p}$ diverges and $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^p}$ converges.

To piece this all together: You know $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}$ converges by the $p$-test.  Therefore, $\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$ converges.  Finally, 
$$
    \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}  + \int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}} 
$$
so the given integral converges.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I get this now. I guess I made a lot of errors there.

Comment: @Wanderer: You're welcome! Don't worry about making mistakes; it's how we learn.

Answer (score 2):

For $x$ close to zero the initial function is bounded, hence it remains to verify convergence on $[T,+\infty)$ for large $T$. And
$$
\int_T^\infty \frac1{x^{3/2}}\,dx
$$
converges.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(x) = (1+x^3)^{-1/2}$ on $x \in [0,\infty)$ is bounded below by $g(x) = 0$, and above by $$h(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & 0 \le x \le 1, \\ x^{-3/2}, & x > 1. \end{cases}.$$  Therefore, $$0 < \int_{x=0}^\infty f(x) \, dx < \int_{x=0}^\infty h(x) \, dx = 1 + \int_{x=1}^\infty x^{-3/2} \, dx = 3.$$

An image for your convenience:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$1/(\sqrt {1+x^3})$ when x close to $0$ we can aproximate as 1+$\binom{{-1}/2}{1}x^{3}$ and this function is integrabile in interval [$0,a],\ a>0$. in $\infty$ you have aproximation integrabile function as $\dfrac {1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ is integrabile in [a,$\infty$].